# Clarification on class $SPP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

A language $L$ is in $SPP$ if there is a $GapP$ function $f$ such that

$x\in L\implies f(x)=1$ and $x\not\in L\implies f(x)=0$.

By $x\not\in L$ I think we mean $x\not\in SPP$ correct?

I would have thought $x\not\in L$ if there is no such $f$. Why is it not defined this way? In this case we have $x:f(x)\not\in\{0,1\}$. Is such $x\in L$ or $x\not\in L$?

I guess my query is it is not clear that in this case $x\in L$ and $x\not\in L$ cover all strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathsf{SPP}$ is a class of languages, so we can ask whether a language is in $\mathsf{SPP}$, not some input in $\Sigma^*$. The function $f$ is fixed before seeing the inputs, as it defines the language. You don't look at the input and then ask if there exists some function.

Think of it this way, $\mathsf{SPP}$ is the class of languages decidable by a certain class of nondeteministic polynomial time machines, namely those for which the difference between the number of accepting and rejecting paths takes values in $\{0,1\}$ (for all inputs). Note that for a general NP machine, given input $x$ this difference can take values in $\{0,1,...,2^{poly(|x|)}\}$. Given such a machine $M$, the associated $\mathsf{SPP}$ language is the set of all inputs for which the difference is $1$.

Comment: What about those with difference $0$ and $\neq1$?

Comment: ' Given such a machine $M$, the associated $\mathsf{SPP}$ language is the set of all inputs for which the difference is $1$.'. What about those with difference $0$ and $>1$? do we categorize difference $0$ inputs as not in the language? Then how about $>1$. I am still confused.

Comment: For $\oplus P$ 'Given such a machine $M$, the associated $\mathsf{\oplus P}$ language is the set of all inputs for which the parity of number of accepting paths is $0$.'. It is clear those not in $\mathsf{\oplus P}$ should have parity $1$. Those with parity $0$ and $1$ cover all possible inputs.

Comment: Similarly to $\mathsf{BPP}$, $\mathsf{SPP}$ is a semantic class, in the sense that not every non deterministic Turing machine defines a language in $\mathsf{SPP}$. For $\oplus P$, take any non deterministic Turing machine, for each input the number of accepting paths is either even or odd, and thus you can associate a $\oplus P$ language to this machine. For $\mathsf{BPP}$ however, if there exists an input for which the acceptance probability is $\frac{1}{2}$, then this machine does not define a $\mathsf{BPP}$ language (should this input be inside or outside the language).

Comment: The same goes for $\mathsf{SPP}$, if an NTM has a difference which is not in $\{0,1\}$, then it does not define an $\mathsf{SPP}$ language.

Comment: So $SPP$ is semantic and $\oplus P$ is syntactic. Isn't then $SPP\neq\oplus P$ true?

Comment: Semantic class is a rather soft term, and to my knowledge there is no widely accepted formal definition. To apply your argument we are going to need formal definitions, otherwise its meaningless. That said, it's the definitions who are semantic, i.e. we are giving a semantic characterization of the class, this doesn't mean a syntactic one does not exist. As an example, although we say the characterization of BPP is semantic, it is still open whether it equals P.

Comment: So if $GapP=\#P$ then does $SPP=UP$ hold? It looks like $UP$ and $SPP$ definitions are similar except for $GapP$ replacing $\#P$ in $SPP$.